# How can I make a group of contacts that have phone numbers with the iPhone label?

Tags: macos, iphone, ios, contacts

I have been editing my contacts in Lion Address Book to use the iPhone label for phone numbers.  I want to create a smart group that shows all contacts that use the iPhone label. I would use this group to share iPhone tips with my contacts.  I do not see a way to create a smart group like this on Lion or iOS.

Comment: This would be useful for me too, but I don't know a way to accomplish it. On Lion, smart group rules operate at the property level (e.g. "email is set", "email contains", "email does not contain"). Smart groups rules do not have an awareness of phone labels.